# values stored in associative arrays are undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays

am making an ajax call to retrive json data

i then store the retrived data into associative arrays

but when i try to get the data from the associative arrays the keys and values in them are undefined
I am guessing its because the the data is getting stored as value[i], and as the loop is finished it no longer knows what i is, how do i go about fixing this?

can be seen on this page http://www.focus-on-plants.com/locator_iconed.php
here is my script

```
myUrl = 'geo_locator_icons.php';// url of php page that retrives the locations
    // start a new ajax call
    $.ajax({  
        type: "GET", //The type of HTTP verb (post, get, etc)  
        url: myUrl, //The URL from the form element where the AJAX request will be sent  
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(dat) { //Triggered after a successful response from server    
            var myData = dat.icons;
            var count = myData.length - 1;
            console.log(dat)
            console.log(myData)

            for(i=0; i < count; i++){
                // Creating the icon 
                var icon_image = "'"+myData.folder_ico+myData.image_ico+"'" //set image
                var icon_size = "new google.maps.Size"+myData.iconsize_ico //set size
                var icon_origin = "new google.maps.Point(0, 0)" // The origin
                var icon_anchor = "new google.maps.Point"+myData.iconanchor_ico //set anchorpoint
                // Creating the shadow
                var shadow_image = "'"+myData.folder_ico+myData.shadow_ico+"'" //set image
                var shadow_size = "new google.maps.Size"+myData.shadowsize_ico //set size
                var shadow_origin = null // The origin
                var shadow_anchor = "new google.maps.Point"+myData.iconanchor_ico //set anchorpoint
                // Creating the shape
                var shape_type = 'poly'
                var shape_coord = myData.imagemap_ico
                // Creating the icon
                var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(icon_image);
                // Creating the shadow
                var shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
                    shadow_image,
                    shadow_size,
                    shadow_origin,
                    shadow_anchor
                );
                // Creating a shape
                var shape = '{type: '+shape_type+', coord:'+shape_coord+'}'

                // add the icon to the mapIconsArray
                iconImageArray[myData.name_ico] = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
                    icon_image,
                    icon_size,
                    icon_origin,
                    icon_anchor
                );
                // add the icon to the shadowIconsArray
                iconShadowArray[myData.name_ico] = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
                    shadow_image,
                    shadow_size,
                    shadow_origin,
                    shadow_anchor
                );
                // add the shape to the shapeIconsArray
                iconShapeArray[myData.name_ico] = shape
            };
        },
        error: function(dat) { //Triggered if an error communicating with server   
            $("#geo_detail").append('<label>There was an error retriving the Icons: '+dat+'<label><br>');
            $('#loc_button').fadeIn('slow');
            return 0;
        },  
    });
    console.log(iconImageArray)
    console.log(iconShadowArray)
    console.log(iconShapeArray)
```

<-----------------------update on what i am trying to achive-------------------->

The `createIcons()` function will run when the page loads after the map initialises.

I want it to store the data into the 3 arrays(now objects) i have created

`var iconImageArray = {};
var iconShadowArray = {};
var iconShapeArray = {};`

i have a function called `addMarkers()` which adds markers to the map i want to be able to change the marker image depending on the type of marker that is added.

the add marker script:

```
// ADD MARKER FUNCTION
// Adds a marker to the map
// PARAMS: 
// @myLatrLng - latLng object
// @dat - Data containg location Info
function addMarker(map, myData){
    // Create the marker
    // create the marker info first
    myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(myData.lat_mdt, myData.lng_mdt);
    markersArray.push(myLatLng);
    markersInfoArray.push(myData);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
    title: myData.name_mdt,
    icon: iconImageArray[myData.name_etp],
    shadow: iconShadowArray[myData.name_etp],
    shape: iconShapeArray[myData.name_etp],
   });

   // Wrapping the event listener inside an anonymous function
   // that we immediately invoke and passes the variable i to.
   (function(myData, marker) {
       // Creating the event listener. It now has access to the values of
       // myData and marker as they were during its creation
       google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
       //create thecontent for the infowindow
       var content = createContent(myData);
       var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
           content: content
       });
       infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
})(myData, marker);             
};
```

<----------------------update----------------------------------->

well this is where i am at, 
ive done loads of testing with static data and the icons for the map generate fine, so my actual google map code is ok and working.

As soon as i start trying to reference items from the `myIconsArray object` it all breaks and i get no console messages that are set up in the `addMarkers function`.

I do notice however when i look in the console for the `myIcons Array` thwe structure looks incorrect:

within myIconsArray i have 3 objects, icon{} shadow{}, shape{}

shape seems to be ok its ;like this:
shape{ 
    orchid day{
        coord{} 
        type{}
    } 
    stokist{
        coord{} 
        type{}

```
} 
website visitor{
    coord{} 
    type{}

}
```

}

but image and shadow objects have wrong names are like this:

image{ 
    orchid day{
        Na{} //should be size (value is correct)
        anchor{} //shoule be anchorpoint (value is correct)
        b{} should be origin (value is correct)
        hb{} // should be image (value is correct)
        hc{} do not kn ow why this is here is undefined and not used by me!!!
    } 
    stokist{
        coord{} 
        type{}

```
} 
website visitor{
    coord{} 
    type{}

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last 3 `console.log()` show undefined because they run before the response is received from the request.

Any code that relies on the AJAX response needs to be placed in (or called from) the `success:` callback.

So try moving them to the end of your `success:` callback:

```
 success: function(dat) { 
       ...
        // add the icon to the shadowIconsArray
        iconShadowArray[myData.name_ico] = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
            shadow_image,
            shadow_size,
            shadow_origin,
            shadow_anchor
        );
        // add the shape to the shapeIconsArray
        iconShapeArray[myData.name_ico] = shape
    };
    console.log(iconImageArray)
    console.log(iconShadowArray)
    console.log(iconShapeArray)
 }, 
 error: func...
```

**EDIT:** Additional issue was that the `i` variable was not being utilized to get the value of the item at the current iteration in the Array, as in `myData[ i ].name_ico`

Comment: hasnt solved the problem there is 1 row of data in the arrays but where i have put reference to the values from myData array they are all undefined and the associative name i set is undefined also, probably because it overwrites each key each time it stores undefined, if that makes sense...

Comment: @Dizzy - First, if these are not meant to reference values using numeric indexes, you should use an Object instead of an Array. As in `var iconImageArray = {};`. On your page, you still have the `console.log()` calls outside of the `success` callback, so I don't know what's going on. If you're receiving the data you expect, it seems like it should work.

Comment: hi sorry ive been testing locally so the changes i made arnt up on the server will put it there now, and also create objects instead of arrays,

Comment: still undefined, if i am correct its not working because the values i am storing (now into objects) are referecing values from the ajax call in the createIcons() function, so when the function is finished the data no longer exists so is undefined? or am i totally wrong and is something else, really it would be best if i could store the data into global objects so that all the functions i have can access the data.

Comment: @Dizzy - First, let me know what I need to do on your page to run that code. Regarding the data storage, if you're referring to the use of `myData.name_ico` as the `"key"` for the value you're storing in the Object, then no, that becomes a permanent key unless you delete that `key/value` pair. If you meant the `new google.maps.MarkerImage(` that you're storing as the value, again no, that will be retained in memory as long as it is referenced somewhere, like your object.

Comment: @Dizzy - I see one issue. When you create the `count` variable, you're doing `length - 1`, but then in the `for` loop, you're doing `i < count`. So if there's only one row, then `i===0` and `count===0` so `i` is never less than `count` and the code in the loop never fires. I'd get rid of the `- 1` from the `count` assignment unless you were hoping to exclude the last item.

Comment: @Dizzy - Sorry for all the comments, but one more thing. Because you're using a `for` loop to access each item in the `myData` array, you need to utilize the `i` variable to get the item at the current iteration, as in `myData[ i ].folder_ico` or `myData[ i ].name_ico`. The `myData` is an Array (with numeric indexes) right?

Comment: ahhhh maybe thats where ive gone wrong, see my edit in the question to see what it is i am trying to achieve

Comment: @Dizzy - I saw your edit, and now I'm seeing the console logs. Yes the missing `[ i ]` is why you're getting `undefined`. Also, you'll not get the last item in the Array unless you remove the `- 1` from the `count` variable assignment.

Comment: this is a steep learning curve, i keep missing so many things out, the [i] from the myData fixed it, thanks for your help, i dont know what i would do withoout the people here! i hope once i am proficient i csan help others as much as i have been helped.

Comment: can you update your answer to include the [i] and i'll check it as correct thanks

Comment: @Dizzy - I'll update. Someone once said that a steep learning curve is a good thing because it means you're learning a lot in a short amount of time. :o)

Comment: @Dizzy - Off topic a little, but don't forget to use the `var` keyword when creating the `i` variable for the loop. This will keep `i` a local variable. `for(var i=0; i < count; i++){...`

Comment: seems to be running without errors now but my markers arnt showing on the map, it zooms after the search is performed so am guessing they must be there

Comment: @Dizzy - Looks like you're back to using Arrays instead of Objects again. This isn't the issue, but Objects should really be used. Also, in the console, the Arrays appear to be empty again. I'll take a closer look.

Comment: @Dizzy - I see you have Objects now. Maybe it was cached. Anyway, when I do a search, Paris for example, I get a bunch of 404 errors in the console pertaining to images. Not sure what's happening, but I'd start investigating there.

Comment: yeah its putting the whole strin in for the image, i thin k i need to somehow have seperate items in each of the main objects, so iconImageArray would have another array called image,size,location etc etc

Comment: probably best to search within the uk i dont think there are many locations outside the uk...

Comment: @Dizzy - Map isn't loading. You've got a Parse Error because of `line 102: var icon_origin = '(0,0') // The origin`. Quotation marks are misplaced. I'll check back in a bit.

Comment: have to  stop for now am getting there will carry on tomorrow, thanks for the help :)

Comment: thanks for all your help patrick i am on the verge of solving this, the question has changes somewhat so i have started a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157414/google-maps-v3-setting-marker-size-dynamically