# google maps v3 setting marker size dynamically

Tags: javascript, object, google-maps-api-3

heres the problem, i have a database thats hold information on marker images:

i'm retreiving all that  with an ajax call and saving the data as objects, so i can check the location type of the marker and place the appropriate marker for that type of location.

am reciving the data fine but when i try to add the data into the contructor for a new google map image it errors, i have checked with an alert that the right information is there and it is so what gives???

```
// the following code will wor!!!
                   new google.maps.Size(32,37) // The Size works
//The following line breaks it with dynamic value    
                   new google.maps.Size(myIconArray.icon[myData.name_etp].size)
```

heres the full code: 
(the test values in the static lines of code are the same values that are stored in the object references i am making)
http://www.focus-on-plants.com/locator_iconed.php

```
function addMarker(map, myData){
      console.log(myData)
      // Create the marker
      // create the marker info first
      myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(myData.lat_mdt, myData.lng_mdt);
      markersArray.push(myLatLng);
      markersInfoArray.push(myData);

      // ----------------------------
      // NOW CREATE THE ACTUAL ICON
       //alert( myIconArray.icon[myData.name_etp].size)

      /*var iconimage = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
       '/images/icons/markers/flower_lb/image_med.png', //myIconArray.icon[myData.name_etp].image,
       new google.maps.Size(myIconArray.icon[myData.name_etp].size) // The Size
       //new google.maps.Point(myIconArray.icon[myData.name_etp].origin), // The origin
       //new google.maps.Point(myIconArray.icon[myData.name_etp].anchorpoint) // The anchor
      );*/
      //console.log(iconimage)
      var iconshape = {
       type: 'poly',
       coord: [0,2,1,2,1,1,18,0,18,1,19,2,20,19,19,19,18,21,14,21,10,26,5,21,1,21,1,20,0,20,0,2]
      }

      //alert(myIconArray.shape[myData.name_etp])
      mySize = 'new google.maps.Size('+myIconArray.icon[myData.name_etp].size+')'
      var iconimage = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
       myIconArray.icon[myData.name_etp].image,
       // the following code works!!!
                        new google.maps.Size(32,37) // The Size works
                       //The following line breaks iot with dynamic value    
                       //new google.maps.Size(myIconArray.icon[myData.name_etp].size) 


       //new google.maps.Point(0, 0), // The origin
       //new google.maps.Point(13,29) // The anchor
      );
      var iconshadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
       '/images/icons/markers/flower_lb/shadow_med.png',
       new google.maps.Size(42,18), // The Size
       new google.maps.Point(0,0), // The origin
       new google.maps.Point(13,18) // The anchor
      );

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: myLatLng,
       map: map,
       title: myData.name_mdt,
       icon: iconimage,
       shadow: iconshadow//,
       //shape: iconshape
      });

      // Wrapping the event listener inside an anonymous function
      // that we immediately invoke and passes the variable i to.
      (function(myData, marker) {
       // Creating the event listener. It now has access to the values of
       // myData and marker as they were during its creation
       google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        //create thecontent for the infowindow
        var content = createContent(myData);
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
         content: content
        });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
       });
      })(myData, marker);  

     };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok so i found out why this was,

i was passing `new google.maps.Size(myIconArray.icon[myData.name_etp].size)`

google image maps.size takes two seperate parameters, `new google.maps.Size(42,18)`

i was passing `32, 37` which was actualy a string,

i needed to split the string up using the following:

`tmp = myIconArray.icon[myData.name_etp].size.split(",")`

then to add the x and y for the size i use: `new google.maps.Size(tmp[0], tmp[1])`